# Can not update drupal/core with composer

Tags: composer

Can not update drupal/core to 8.6.11

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.6.11
```

shows

```
webflo/drupal-core-require-dev  8.6.10  requires  drupal/core (8.6.10)
```

How can I solve it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is, that drupal/core and webflo/drupal-core-require-dev always have to point to the very same version.

If you use `composer update` composer will look for this and pull the needed actual versions alone.

There are some articles recommending not to do so, but instead to update in minor parts and specify a concrete packet for better testing and reverting possibilities if something goes wrong. This means typing:

`composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`

This may be true, but I often run in such errors with dependencies then I have to solve myself. You have now to specify both packets in the same command, then it will work too:

`composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies`

My private conclusion:

- If I have time to go the suggested way and solve such dependencies, than I will specify the single packet to update.
- If it makes problems and I have an actual backup of my codebase and my database (as you should alwas have before updating anything!) and have not so much time, I simple type `composer update` and mostly all will work out of the box at the first try.

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
composer update
```

did the trick by have no idea why

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

did not ...

final result is:

```
  - Updating drupal/core (8.6.10 => 8.6.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating webflo/drupal-core-require-dev (8.6.10 => 8.6.11)
```