# update drupal core from a version to a new version with composer

Tags: updating, composer

i want to update the core from 8.7.6 to 8.9.2 and when I try this command "**composer require drupal/core:^8.9.2 --update-with-dependencies**" i have got an error like below , can anyone help me please to solve this and get the migration work

the error :

```
 Problem 1
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.7.6 requires drupal/core 8.7.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.7.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.7.6 requires drupal/core 8.7.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.7.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.7.6 requires drupal/core 8.7.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.7.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for webflo/drupal-core-require-dev (locked at 8.7.6, required as ^8.7.0) -> satisfiable by webflo/drupal-core-require-dev[8.7.6].
```

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "harvesthq/chosen",
                "version": "1.8.7",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.8.7/chosen_v1.8.7.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "composer/installers": "^1.2.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.27",
        "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^4.22",
        "drupal/bootstrap_layouts": "^5.1",
        "drupal/bootstrap_sass": "^1.9",
        "drupal/chosen": "^2.8",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.1",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.4",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core": "8.7.6",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.1",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.4",
        "drupal/eu_cookie_compliance": "^1.8",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
        "drupal/google_tag": "^1.2",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^1.29",
        "drupal/memcache": "^2.0",
        "drupal/menu_admin_per_menu": "^1.0",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.0",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.4",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.4",
        "drupal/robotstxt": "^1.2",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.3",
        "drupal/sitemap": "^1.5",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^4.1",
        "drupal/yaml_editor": "^1.0",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "harvesthq/chosen": "^1.8",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.7.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make your composer.json look more like the latest https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/composer.json. Note the require-dev and scaffold section. Remove the old scaffold package. Also you currently locked core at 8.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would try:

**composer require webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.9.2**

If that fails try deleting the composer.lock file and then running
**composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies**

If your composer.json requirement for drupal/core isn't allowing the jump to 8.9.2, then update that and run the second command again.

Comment: thank you for your res , but i have tried your logic but still have the same error

Comment: Can you add your composer.json file for review?

Comment: yes see above in the detail

Comment: Try updating your drupal core requirement. "drupal/core": "^8.9.2", in the JSON file and then run composer update --with-dependencies

Comment: after done that , i have ran drush cr and it gives me this   "The service "redirect.request_subscriber" has a dependency on a non-existent service "path_alias.manager".  "

Comment: You need to run drush updb. After core upgrade. Take backup before proceeding

Comment: webflo/drupal-core-require-dev is abandoned. Use drupal/core-dev instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have often read this is not the recommended way, but in my Drupal installations I get fewest problems with a simple

```
composer update
```

command.
This updates all, and solves such dependencies reliable.

Another solution is to combine core and webflo/drupal-core-require-dev in the same composer command:

```
composer update drupal/core:^8.9.2 webflo/drupal-core-require-dev:^8.9.2 --with-dependencies
```

Always backup your database and codebase before, so you can switch back if something went terribly wrong.

It could be helpful to read the release notes of the core and module version steps between your upgrade. Sometimes there are important hints.

Comment: A more extensive answer you can find in this older similar question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277719/can-not-update-drupal-core-with-composer/277733#277733